# Why can the AppDelegate file not see the GameAnalytics file?

Tags: xcode, buildbox, gameanalytics

I'm trying to add the GameAnalytics SDK to my project (a game),
dragged the framework file onto the project, but when I import it I get an error
saying that the file `GameAnalytics/GameAnalytics.h is not found`  How can I fix that problem?

Comment: Import framework in your targets `Build Phases > Embed Frameworks`.

Comment: Please include the content, not just a picture, as, the picture may not display well on some (e.g. mobile) devices and does not make it easy for anyone to try to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @EmreCiftci it works,

thanks

Comment: Hi @MohamedAwad, I shared it as an answer so that others could also benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import framework to your target:

```
Build Phases > Embed Frameworks + <Your Framework>
```

I hope it is works.

Enjoy.